# Create dynamic classname followed by incrementing value with Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that renders a list.  Each item has a classname.  My question is how can I dynamically add a classname followed by an incrementing value.

```
function Menu(props) {
    const list = ['list1', 'list2', 'list3']
    const menuitems = list.map((list, index) => {
        return <li className="menuitem" key={index}>{list}</li>
    })

    return (
        <ul>{menuitems}</ul>
    )
}
```

In the DOM, it should look like this:

```
<ul>
    <list class="menuitem item-1">list1</li>
    <list class="menuitem item-2">list2</li>
    <list class="menuitem item-3">list3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can add a incrementing value as the state of the class and increase every time you want dynamically add a classname, so create a function that add to the list this classname. The renderPart of the list you already have done it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty simple =)

```
function Menu(props) {
    const list = ['list1', 'list2', 'list3']
    const menuitems = list.map((list, index) => {
        return <li className={`menuitem item-${index + 1}`} key={index}>{list}</li>
    })

    return (
        <ul>{menuitems}</ul>
    )
}
```

It uses JSX Expression `{ - expression code lives here - }`. You can place any valid [JS expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Expressions) between curly braces.

Comment: I'm glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

> **Try This :**

```
function Menu(props = null) {
    const list = ['list1', 'list2', 'list3']
    const menuitems = list.map((list, index) => {
        return `<li className="menuitem item-${index + 1}" key="${index}">${list}</li>`
    });

    return (
        `<ul>${menuitems.join(" ")}</ul>`
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use package called **classnames** or:

```
<li className={`menuitem-${index}`} key={index}>{list}</li>
```

Comment: This is hhelpful too. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
const menuitems = list.map((list, index) => {
        return <li className={`menuitem item-{index+1}`} key={index}>{list}</li>
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

**This should work**

```
function Menu(props) {
    const list = ['list1', 'list2', 'list3']
    const menuitems = list.map((list, index) => {<li className=`menuitem itme-${index + 1}>{list}</li>})
    return <ul>{menuitems}</ul> 
}
```